Sewoo printer with ZPL
How can I make the Sewoo printer work well with ZPL?
The zpl doesn't follow the instructions of (x,y) and always starts at the center of the label.
For example I have that ZPL Script:
^XA
^MMT
^PW839
^LL0240
^LS0
^FT24,62^A0N,39,33^FH\^FD{{Descricao1}}^FS
^FT40,217^A0B,23,21^FH\^FD{{Data}}^FS
^FT55,102^A0N,23,24^FH\^FD{{Curva}}^FS
^FT48,221^A0N,23,19^FH\^FD{{EAN}}^FS
^FT48,243^BQN,2,3
^FH\^FDLA,{{EAN}};{{QRPrecoVigorInteiro}}.{{QRPrecoVigorDecimal}}^FS
^FT131,106^A0N,20,26^FH\^FDNesta Embal^FS
^FT131,130^A0N,20,26^FH\^FDO {{UnidadeMedida}} sai por^FS
^FT131,175^A0N,37,38^FH\^FDR$ {{CalculoKgLt}}^FS
^FT341,188^A0N,39,36^FH\^FDR$^FS
^FT398,223^A0N,130,115^FH\^FD{{PrecoVigor}}^FS
^LRY^FO327,83^GB440,0,152^FS^LRN
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

Am I missing something to make the script work well with Sewoo? I've changed the paper configuration to lose some margin, but doesn't follow the script yet.

Try setting label home to 0,0 using ^LH0,0.  Put it at the top of the label format, after the ^XA.
